# Close all webdriver sessions using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running a Flask server and I have the following problem.

When an user login in, a `Selenium webdriver` is initialized and performs some task. It store some cookies and then it communicates with frontend (I can't control WHEN it will save the cookies and I cannot close it with `driver.close()`. After this I need to start again the `chromedriver` but preserving the cookies (I'm using `User dir` for this reason and this works).

The problem is that the second time I start the `webdriver` I get error because the previous one is not closed. How can I close it before starting a new one, using Python?

Thanks!

I expect to close all the active `chromedriver` sessions without using Selenium (I cannot use it), but using Python.

Comment: You could use `psutil` to kill the chromedriver process.

Comment: how to do that in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you want to `driver.quit()` to gracefully close all browser windows (note that `driver.close()` only closes the window in focus). If that's not possible, you can use [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) to kill the chromedriver processes:

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if 'chromedriver' in proc.name():
       proc.kill()
```

A similar approach can work with the built-in `subprocess`, but maybe with a few extra steps depending on your OS.

Comment: Thanks!
However, I get the following: ` SandboxOriginDatabase failed at: Init@storage\browser\file_system\sandbox_origin_database.cc:94 with error: IO error: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System\Origins/LOCK: File currently in use. (ChromeMethodBFE: 15::LockFile::2)`

Comment: Have you tried to wait a little after killing  `chromedriver` processes and before starting a new one? Maybe it needs some time to finally kill the process and remove locks from files.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the cookies ina  txt file, and every time you run the drive, you add the cookies with 'driver.get_cookies()', 'drive.add_cookie()' and these structure:

```
    content_cookies = {
        'name': <NAME_VARIABLE_COOKIE>,
        'domain': '<URLSITE>',
        'value': str(<VALUE_VARIABLE_COOKIE>)
    }
    driver.add_cookie(content_cookies)
```

Comment: The problem is that the cookie will be saved in asynchronous way in the selected `user dir` but at that moment I have no more the `driver` control, so I cannot save anything. Now I was just using `user dir` so the next time I open the `driver` I have the cookie, but I cannot save it